# remove jQuery function does not work with ie7 (removing td tags)

Tags: jquery

I have this code ([jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/y08qr7en/6/)) and all the remove functions work except for the part where I'm removing the td tags.

my code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="class" rowspan="3">(1)</td>
        <td class="class">02&nbsp;mar&nbsp;-&nbsp;02&nbsp;mar</td>
        <td class="class">tuesday
            <br>(once-only)</td>
        <td class="class">800&nbsp;-&nbsp;900</td>
        <td class="class">biological&nbsp;sciences, lecture&nbsp;theatre</td>
        <td class="class">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class" rowspan="999">(1)</td>
        <td class="class">27&nbsp;apr&nbsp;-&nbsp;27&nbsp;apr</td>
        <td class="class">tuesday
            <br>(once-only)</td>
        <td class="class">800&nbsp;-&nbsp;900</td>
        <td class="class">biological&nbsp;sciences, lecture&nbsp;theatre</td>
        <td class="class">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="class" rowspan="999">(1)</td>
        <td class="class">18&nbsp;may&nbsp;-&nbsp;18&nbsp;may</td>
        <td class="class">tuesday
            <br>(once-only)</td>
        <td class="class">800&nbsp;-&nbsp;900</td>
        <td class="class">biological&nbsp;sciences, lecture&nbsp;theatre</td>
        <td class="class">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="http://google.com">link1</a><br>
<a href="http://google.com">link2</a><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link3</a><br>
<a href="http://google.com">link4</a><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link5</a><br>
<br>
<button>remove</button>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        $("td[rowspan='999']").remove();
        $("a[target='_blank']").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix/solve this? I've searched the net but can't find anything there.

Thanks very much

ps. This same code works fine in recent browsers and IE8+. **I am using native IE7 browser to test.**

edit1: edited code to include $(document).ready. still not working.

edit2: included  below the original jquery line and still not working.

edit3: tried using http:// in the script src and no change.

edit4: tried using jquery 1.8.3, 1.9.0 and 1.9.1 and it doesn't work.

edit5: enclosed parameter values in double quotes

Comment: write code inside it  `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`

Comment: what is the jQuery version used

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.11.1.min.js and I've already edited code to include $(document).ready. still not working. thanks

Comment: add  jquery migrate plugin and  check <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The `Jquery` was not downloaded from the provided link

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

prefix the link with `http`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

When i tried the above, the `remove` worked for me..

Comment: if that's the case, the other remove lines wouldn't have worked? edit: just tried your suggestion. it doesn't work. thanks though!

Comment: Did the issue occurred in native `IE7` or compatibility view? So far i check this in compatibility view all the line are executed properly for me..

Answer (score 0):

None of your attributes are declared correctly. You need to put quotes around the values. For example, your first few lines should look like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="class" rowspan="3">(1)</td>
    <td class="class">02&nbsp;mar&nbsp;-&nbsp;02&nbsp;mar</td>
    <td class="class">tuesday
        <br>(once-only)</td>
    <td class="class">800&nbsp;-&nbsp;900</td>
    <td class="class">biological&nbsp;sciences, lecture&nbsp;theatre</td>
    <td class="class text-left stream">
        <div class="left"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Same thing in your jQuery code, I'm not sure why you would have it declared both the correct way, and the incorrect way right after each other, remove this line which doesn't have the inner - single quotes:

```
    $("td[rowspan=999]").remove();
```

Additionally, what doctype are you using? I know that jQuery has some specific bugs with different doctypes, especially if you don't have one declared and you're defaulting to quarks mode.

Comment: 1. edited my table to enclosed parameter values in double quotes. no effect. 2. no specific doctype as you can see from the code. what you see is what you get. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per jquery support, 1.11.0 and 2.0  version not support to ie8 later. So go with 1.9.0.

```
> https://jquery.com/browser-support/
> 
> http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/
```

No I will check by given reference in 1.9.0, still issue with loading in compatibility view. Jquery loaded in jsfiddle, but not loaded other js. There are 2 possibilities. Eigher other js is not support for ie7 or some thing we missing reference as per ie7 standarad of jquery.

So my recommendation is , use simple html and run the same code. May be jsfiddle is not work in ie7.

This I updated of js ref of 1.9.0.
    http://jsfiddle.net/y08qr7en/7/

Comment: just tried using 1.8.3 to 1.9.1 and it doesn't work. thanks though! :)

Comment: Why you want to support or goes to ie7, Ideally in current situaltion, no body can support for ie7 and latter , even ie8 is also not supported in some situation like html5.